# how to map a default controller on aspnet core mvc without the default layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created a .NET Core 3.1 ASPNET project. By default, the startup page us the Home Controller/Index page.

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

But I want to make a Login Page, so I Created a New Controller with a new Action and I passed on the parameter, but instead of ONLY render the Login Page, it renders inside of the "@RenderBody()" from the layout project. On .NET MVC5 it only rendered the page that I set. I already tried with :

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

And it's the same thing. The login page it's not rendered apart of the layout

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with routing.

If you look in your Views folder, there will be a file called _ViewStart.cshtml, containing this code:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

_ViewStart.cshtml runs for every view, so by default it sets the layout page to _Layout.cshtml.

There are 2 options:

- Remove the code from _ViewStart.cshtml, meaning the `Layout` needs to be explicitly set in each view.
- In your login view, set `Layout` to `null`.